# mysql_real_escape_string still showing \

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to safely add a post but I wont to be able to add apostrophes for words like don't. When I use the code below, it adds it into the database like "don\t" but when I want to  display it I only want it to show "don't". Looking around many people are saying you dont need to do anything more just call it from the database and others are saying do other things. Clearly I can not just leave it because it is still showing as "don\t"

```
$stmt = db::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO Posts (postedByUserID, postTitle, postCatID, postDate, postContent) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isiss', $inUserID, mysql_real_escape_string($inPostTitle), $inPostCatID, $postDate, mysql_real_escape_string($inPostContent));
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it - you don't need to escape it if you are using bind_param style input to the database.  It will escape it for you - in essence you've escaped it twice?

Comment: Ok, but when I remove mysql_real_escape_string it won't allow me to put don't in a post. Any reason? No I am using msqli

Comment: No problem, It is working now. I removed mysql_real_escape_string and it is now working. Strange that it wasn't before.

Comment: Check you are using bind_param everywhere you store the post? Check for the initial creation vs editing etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities($postVariable) before passing it to your database.
When you are retrieving it from the database use html_entity_decode($postVariable) and it should display "don't" properly.